# style won't apply to list

Tags: html, css

I have html of the following structure:

```
<div class="property-desc clearfix">
        <div class="left">
            <ul class="prop-iconlist">
                <li class="pdf"><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
                <li class="text"><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
                <li class="htm"><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
                <li class="doc"><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
                <li class="text"><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to apply styles to the a tag in the list item:

```
.prop-iconlist li a {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
color: 
#676767;
}
```

but somehow, the styles for a of property-desc .left seems to apply to it.

```
.property-desc .left a {
font-weight: bold;
color: 
#5473ba;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-weight: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

How may i apply the style I want to the a in the list item? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.property-desc .left a` is more specific than `.prop-iconlist li a`. The best way would probably to make `.property-desc .left a` less specific, or change it to `.property-desc .left > a`, or something. It depends on the situation.

If that rule absolutely can’t be reasoned with, you can always make a (gasp) special case that overrides the overridden:

```
.property-desc .prop-iconlist li a {
    /* Repeat some things here */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.prop-iconlist li a`, this selector is less specific than `.property-desc .left a`. As a result the first selector is not working.

To solve this problem you can make the first selector more specific than the last one or making the last one less specific than the first one. Either way will work just fine.

`.left .prop-iconlist li a`(more specific first selector than `.property-desc .left a`, so it will work)

`.left a`(less specific last selector than `.prop-iconlist li a`, so this selector will not work and the first selector will work)

you can google about css-selector-specificity and learn more about this topic. And to check which selector is more specific you can visit to this site(http://specificity.keegan.st/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to read up on selector specificity. Basically different types of selectors have higher weighting when determining which style rules to apply. In this case, a class selector has a higher weighting than an element selector, so your second rule which uses 2 class selectors overrides the first which has only 1.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Comment: That explains the why, but doesn’t explain the how. To fix it, that is.

Comment: True. But once you understand the why, the how becomes obvious - and you are then also armed with the knowledge necessary to overcome similar issues in the future.